# What happens to electrons in a light bulb?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

In a circuit with 5V DC battery and a light bulb of certain resistance, electrons enter through one terminal and come out of the other. And its evident that the current is same throughout the circuit.
My question is,
What is the **Difference** between the electron that entered the bulb and the electron that come out, there must be some because the electrons are responsible for the bulb's glow. And also the reason can't be Kinetic Energy because if electrons have a loss of speed in the bulb then **dq/dt** or current entering or leaving must be different.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons are accelerated by the field inside the incandescent filament (the voltage drop over the light bulb is large, the field is relatively strong). The electron then interacts with the lattice, losing its energy to thermal vibrations. Then gets accelerated again, etc.

Theory for this is classical Drude model, with a relaxation time tau of about 10^-14 seconds.

Comment: I can't understand the difference between the entering electron and the electron that comes out. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @mobifz96 There is no difference. (Except for a difference in potential (potential energy) as explained in thr answer by @freecharly.)

Answer (score 1):

The difference of the electrons entering the filament and exiting the filament is the the difference in potential energy due to the voltage drop of $5V$ between the terminals. An electron entering at the negative terminal has a potential energy $$E_{pot}= q⋅V=1,6⋅10^{-19} C ⋅ 5V=8.0⋅10^{-19} J$$ This potential energy is transformed into electron kinetic energy and subsequently into heat by collisions of the electron with the metal ions of the filament. At the positive terminal, the exiting electron has zero potential energy and the same mean kinetic energy as the entering electron.